# Angular 17 new builder can't run server.mjs

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular17

I updated my projecto Angular 17.1 and now when i try ng build it creates a server.mjs file in /dist//server directory which is meant to be served for production. when I try to run the file with node or pm2 i get the following error

```
TypeError: Nl is not a function
    at $C (file:///Users/goldenfox/Projects/front/dist/karlancer/server/server.mjs:106:5771)
    at GC (file:///Users/goldenfox/Projects/front/dist/karlancer/server/server.mjs:106:6227)
    at file:///Users/goldenfox/Projects/front/dist/karlancer/server/server.mjs:106:6318
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)

Node.js v20.11.0
```

Any Idea about how I can fix this ?

Comment: can you try to build your app without minification/mangling and then run it? error should be much more helpful then

Comment: @Andrei It would really help if you tell me how to turn that off, I tried setting "optimization": false and "sourceMap": true and "namedChunks": true in angular.json but the error didn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting optimization flag to false helped me find out that the problem was importing `import express from 'express';` in server.ts file, This package needs setting this flag `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in angularCompilerOptions of tsconfing.json in Angular 17.